# Чтение файла в строку char *

Tags: c, файлы

Есть такая лаба. Нужно найти в книге *.txt фразу "ХХХ". И вывести сколько раз она была найдена и время поиска. Поиск сделать 3мя алгоритмами. С алгоритмами я разобрался. А вот с, казалось бы, самым простым не справляюсь. Не знаю как из файла запихать в строку текст. 
Вот кусочек кода по считыванию:

```
int main(void)
{
    char * test = NULL;
    book = fopen ("Blood_of_Cain.txt", "r");

    if (book != NULL) 
    {
        fseek(book,0,SEEK_END);
        size_book = ftell (book);
        fseek(book, 0, SEEK_SET);

        test = (char *) malloc(size_book * sizeof (char));  
        while (!feof(book)) 
        {
            fgets(test, size_book-1, book);
        }
    }

    free(test);
    fclose(book);
}
```

Здесь я выделяю память для строки ровно столько, сколько весит файл. Потому что размер файла равен кол-ву символов, кодировка ANSI. 
 И код в принципе работает, если только ни одно НО. В строку test попадает текущая строка книги. И в итоге в переменной test оказывается только лишь последняя строка книги. 
Как мне это исправить? 
**Как соединять строки в СИ?**
Или может делать поиск для каждой строки книги? Внутри цикла обхода по файлу? (Мне это не нравится, т.к. думаю это сожрёт больше ресурсов, но вдруг такой вариант лучше)

Comment: @iproger, про `fread` и весь файл Вам уже рассказали. 

А чтение по строкам можно сделать в таком простом цикле:

    char *t;
    for (t = test; fgets(t, size_book, book); t += strlen(t));

В данном случае вызывать `fgets` с размером буфера `size_book` вполне безопасно.

Кстати, `malloc` надо делать на байт больше, чем размер файла (для завершающего нуля), а читать весь файл эффективнее `read` (см. man 2 read`), а не `fread`.

Comment: Угу, очень правильное замечание.

Но всё же я бы не применял настолько лаконичный синтаксис. Для новичков это вполне покажется нечитаемым. (Хотя сам тоже грешу, да.)

Comment: Да, gcc -std=gnu99 (или можно -std=c99)

    for (char *t = ....; ...

Comment: @avp: Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в строке

```
fgets(test, size_book-1, book);
```

Каждую новую строку вы записываете в то же самое место, затирая старую.

Попробуйте завести отдельный указатель на текущую позицию, куда надо писать в буфере, и продвигать её после каждой прочитанной строки.

Ещё проще, однако, не читать файл построчно, а сразу весь — вы ведь знаете его длину!

```
fread(test, size_book, 1, book);
```

— читает весь файл. Не забудь дописать в конец `\0` — функция `fread` не сделает это сама.

Если вы уж пишете на C, вы должны понимать, как устроены сишные строки.

В C строка — не высокоуровневый объект, это просто кусок памяти, заканчивающийся на `\0`. Соответственно, чтобы дописать к существующей строке, нужно

1. убедиться, что в выделенном куске памяти достаточно местa для дописываемой информации (строка может занимать меньше места, чем выделенная память, и обычно так и делает).
2. дописать в хвост новый кусок, затерев финальный `\0`.
3. не забыть дописать `\0` в конец

Пункты 2 и 3 делает для вас функция `strcat`. Но можно и вручную, один несчастный цикл.

В вашем случае, однако, склеивать строки не нужно, достаточно просто читать следующую строку по адресу финального нуля прочитанного текста. Но `fread` всё равно намного лучше.

Comment: так я поэтому и спрашиваю, покажите пожалуйста как соеденять строки. Например в высокоуровневом языке достаточно было бы просто $test .= fgets(...)

Comment: Да, fread надо попробовать! Спасибо! Но всё-таки если не сложно покажите как в СИ строки соединять.

Comment: @iproger: да, дописал.

Comment: @VladD, Огромное спасибо, лучше чем препод объяснили про строки, теперь я точно всё понял. А то он говорил что оканчивается на \0 но не понятно зачем, почему. Спасибо! Теперь всё понял!

Comment: @iproger: Пожалуйста! Рад, что смог помочь!

Comment: @iproger: добавил насчёт финального нуля.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте fread, она прочитает сразу всё содержимое файла в буфер.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

```
fread(test /*куда читать*/, 1/*размер читаемой структуры*/, size_book/*сколько читать*/, book /*из какого файла*/)
```

Касательно Вашей проблемы

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

> Reads characters from stream and
> stores them as a C string into str
> until (num-1) characters have been
> read or **either a newline or the
> end-of-file is reached**, whichever
> happens first.

Сначала fgets читает до первого переноса строки, затем проверка дочитали ли до конца файла? Нет, не дочитали, читает снова, уже до второго переноса строки. И т.д. до тех пор, пока не дошли до конца файла. В итоге в буфере будет последняя строка.